# Using Azure GraphClient API how can you create a new Native Application?

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory

It looks like the Application object in `Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient` allows a Webapplication to be created. I cannot see how I can use this to create a new Native application.
thanks

Updates:

```
TaskCompletionSource<string> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();
tcs.SetResult(accessToken);
var graphClient = new ActiveDirectoryClient(
    new Uri($"{GraphApiBaseUrl}{tenantId}"),
    async () => { return await tcs.Task; });
var password = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N");
var cred = new PasswordCredential()
{
    StartDate = DateTime.UtcNow,
    EndDate = DateTime.UtcNow.AddYears(1),
    Value = password
};
var app = await GetApplicationByUrlAsync(accessToken, tenantId, appName, identifierUrl);
if(app == null)
{
    app = new Application()
    {
        DisplayName = appName,
        Homepage = homePageUrl,
        IdentifierUris = new List<string>() { identifierUrl },
        LogoutUrl = logoutUrl,
        ReplyUrls = new List<string>() { replyUrl },
        PasswordCredentials = new List<PasswordCredential>() { cred },
    };
    await graphClient.Applications.AddApplicationAsync(app);
}
```

Comment: Can you share what you've attempted?

Comment: I edited my original post to show my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact that an app is a native client application is identified by the `PublicClient` boolean property on the `Application` object. (See [client types](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-2.1) from the OAuth 2.0 spec.)

So, you could register a native client app with the following code:

```
var app = new Application()
{
    DisplayName = "My native client app",
    ReplyUrls = new List<string>() { "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob" },
    PublicClient = true
};

await graphClient.Applications.AddApplicationAsync(app);

Console.WriteLine("App created. AppId: {0}, ObjectId: {1}", app.AppId, app.ObjectId);
```

Note that the native client app does not have password credentials or key credentials (or any other secret).

Details about these and other properties of `Application` objects are available in the API reference documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/entity-and-complex-type-reference#application-entity

Comment: Fantastic. thanks so much for this information, Philippe