# Using Azure GraphClient API how to grant permissions for a new Application?

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I followed this instruction ([Using Azure GraphClient API how can you create a new Native Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39260721/using-azure-graphclient-api-how-can-you-create-a-new-native-application)) and I could create a native application by Azure Graph Client. However, I don't know how to grant permissions by Graph API.

This is my code:

```
        var app = new Application()
        {
            DisplayName = "appNativeName",

            Homepage = "https://stackoverflow.com",
            RequiredResourceAccess = new List<RequiredResourceAccess>()
            {
                new RequiredResourceAccess {
                    ResourceAppId = "00000002-0000-0000-c000-000000000000", //Azure AD 
                    ResourceAccess = new List<ResourceAccess>
                    {
                        new ResourceAccess {Id = Guid.Parse("my guid id"), Type = "Scope" }
                    }
                }
            },
            PublicClient = true //native app
        };

        await azureADContext.Applications.AddApplicationAsync(app);
        var obj = app.ObjectId;
        var appId = app.AppId;
```

I really appreciate your help.

Comment: This article may be helpful: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/arsen/2017/07/30/azure-ad-how-to-create-oauth2permissiongrant-using-graph-api-grant-permissions-and-consent-for-application/

Comment: Thank you so much. This is what I need